# Calculating e^x by math.h and by own means

Tags: beginner, c, mathematics, numerical-methods

For this program, the user needs to enter an exponent and the program will calculate \$e\$ (Euler's number) to the power of the exponent the user inputs.

This is done by two ways:

1. By the math.h library
2. By a `for` loop (Series)

Then the program calculates the difference of these two functions (which we now call \$d\$) and calculates \$n\$.

\$n = \frac{d}{0,001}\$

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>




main()
{
int a, exponent, h;
float math, iteraties, c, stdio, z, verschil;

    char stop='n';
    while (stop!='j')
    {

      printf("vul exponent in:\t\t");
      scanf("%d",&exponent);
      syntax: math= exp(exponent);
      c=1.0;
      h=0;
      stdio=1.0;
      a=0;
      for (iteraties=1.0; a<1; iteraties++)
      {
        h=h+1;
        Syntax: z= pow(exponent,h);

        c=c*iteraties;
        stdio=stdio+(z/c);
        verschil=math-stdio;
        if(verschil<0.01)
        {
            a=2;
        }
      }
      printf("\nexp (%d) uit math.h is:\t\t%f",exponent, math);
      printf("\nexp (%d) m.b.v. de reeks is:\t%f",exponent,stdio);
      printf("\nhet verschil is: \t\t%f", verschil);
      printf("\naantal iteraties is:\t\t%.f", iteraties);


      printf("\n\nstoppen n/j\t\t\t");
      getchar();
      scanf("%c",&stop);
    }

}
```

Comment: You might have more success if you translate the variables to English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the point of the `syntax:` and `Syntax:` labels?
You don't use them, so remove them.
And if you must use two labels, make them less similar to each other.

When the condition in the `while` loop is true from the start,
consider rewriting it as a `do { ... } while` loop.

You don't need the `a` variable.
You can easily rewrite the program without it.

The coding style is very odd:

- Excessive vertical spacing (many empty lines) at many places
- Too compact: it's recommended to put spaces around operators

Other tips:

- Instead of `h=h+1` you can do `++h`, as you did in the for loop
- Instead of `x = x * y` you can use `x *= y`
- Instead of `x = x + y` you can use `x += y`

With the above suggestions (and some more) applied, the code becomes slightly simpler:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int exponent, h;
    float math, iteraties, c, stdio, z, verschil;

    char stop = 'n';
    do
    {
        printf("vul exponent in:\t\t");
        scanf("%d", &exponent);
        math = exp(exponent);
        c = 1.0;
        h = 0;
        stdio = 1.0;
        for (iteraties = 1.0; ; iteraties++)
        {
            ++h;
            z = pow(exponent, h);

            c *= iteraties;
            stdio += z / c;
            verschil = math - stdio;
            if (verschil < 0.01)
            {
                iteraties++;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\nexp (%d) uit math.h is:\t\t%f",exponent, math);
        printf("\nexp (%d) m.b.v. de reeks is:\t%f",exponent,stdio);
        printf("\nhet verschil is: \t\t%f", verschil);
        printf("\naantal iteraties is:\t\t%.f", iteraties);

        printf("\n\nstoppen n/j\t\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &stop);
    } while (stop != 'j');
}
```

Comment: Adding to this, I believe the inner loop would be much clearer as a `while`. The `for` loop with a `break` and no exit condition in the statement is not very idiomatic. It's ok in such a short program, but I'd much rather initialize `iteraties` on a separate row, and have a `do { ++iteraties; ...... } while (verschil >= 0.01);`. This is much more similar to how I'd think it (go on computing while the difference is too large). It's also easier to add a max number of iterations. This can also be done all in the `for` statement, as @vnp wrote.

Comment: Good point, and if you post as an answer I would upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Naming**.

Avoid single-letter identifiers. Try to give them a meaningful names. For example, `c` is actually a factorial, and is better be called such.

**Algorithm**.

You correctly calculate factorials incrementally. Notice that power factors may also be calculated incrementally:

```
    term = 1.0;
    for (...) {
        term *= exponent / iteraties;
        stdio += term;
        ...
    }
```

which eliminates the unnecessary (and unclear) `h` and `c`.

**Loop organization**.

janos noticed that `a` is superfluous. I make one more step and move the termination test to where it belongs, that is into a loop header:

```
    for (iteraties = 1; math - stdio > 0.001; iteraties++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program keeps on computing until a condition is met. The idiom for this is a `while` loop. It's ok to do it in a `for` loop, although these are usually used when the number of iterations is known in advanced, and `while` loops when it's not (this is not always true but I'd say that following this will cause less surprise, which is [a good thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).

As such, I'd reimplement your loop this way:

```
iteraties = 0;
do
{
    ++iteraties;
    h = h + 1;
    z = pow(exponent,h);

    c = c * iteraties;
    stdio = stdio + (z / c);
}
while (math - stdio < 0.01);
```

Adding `&& (iteraties < MAX_NUM_ITERATIONS)` to the condition is then an easy and readable thing to do.

Also, I'd create a `#define` for `0.01`. Hard-coded values are almost never a good idea.